# Using ggvis in Rnw with knitr

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, ggvis

I wonder if I can use ggvis in .Rnw with knitr. I tried the following code in `RStudio Version 0.98.1091`. But it is not working.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{figure}[H]
<< label = Plot1, fig.lp = "Plot1", fig.cap = "Test Plot" >>=
library(ggvis)
p <- mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>% layer_points()
print(p)     # Commenting this line will compile the document
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It throws the following error:

```
LaTeX errors:
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.70 \end{kframe}<!--html_
                          preserve--><div id="plot_id298740869-container" cl...
! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
```

**Edited**

Commenting the line `print(p)` will compile the document without any error.

Would be sufficient if there is a command like `ggsave()` to save the `ggvis` plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The `export_png` function can create a PNG image from a `ggvis` object.

It uses the `node` javascript interpreter, and `node` needs the `vega` package installed.

At the linux command line, I can do this with:

```
sudo npm -g install vega
```

to install the `vega` package globally using the node package manager. I don't know how you do this on a Windows or Mac box.

Once that's done, you can:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{figure}[H]
<< label = Plot1, fig.lp = "Plot1", fig.cap = "Test Plot" >>=
library(ggvis)
p <- mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>% layer_points()
export_png(p,"Plot1.png")    
@
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Plot1.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

do: `knit2pdf("gg.Rnw")`

and get:

[image]

Note you'll have to add captions and labels manually. Perhaps Yihui can be persuaded to integrate this better into knitr, or there may be a way using some of the knitr hooks. Anyway, concept proved...

Comment: I like `ggplot2` and use frequently. But some functionalities are not available in `ggplot2` especially x-axis on the top which is available in `ggvis`. Is there any way to save `ggvis` plots in `pdf` or  `png` format using commands? Thanks

Comment: You'd have to control a browser to open the generated HTML and save a PDF via the browser's "print" functionality. Doable but not simple...

Comment: Please see my edits. Would be sufficient if there is a command like `ggsave()` to save the `ggvis` plots.

Comment: If you install some other things you may be able to create a PNG via ggvis::export_png - once I get this working I might edit my answer for you...

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman for your help. I'm waiting for your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: (+1) Thanks Spacedman for your help. Looks good workaround eventhough I'm struggling with installing vega on Ubuntu 14.04. See if @Yihui has better solution.

Comment: Anything Yihui can do will be dependent on vega and node, I think.

Comment: Have posted a issue/feature req on knitr github https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/906

Comment: This approach works fine with simple graphs but fails with some advanced graphs such as with grouped data. For example fails here `mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~hp, y = ~mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% export_png()`. This problem has been also mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggvis/eQ4XHmRnCCc).

Comment: I've filed that as a bug report on the ggvis github issues site, which is probably the right place. Follow it here: https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/332

Comment: Where can I get vg2png or Vega for Windows?

Comment: Maybe someone could get it on Windows using the package rsvg or svglite or the export_svg function of DiagrammeRsvg.  I couldn't.

Comment: I get two errors: "the marginal notes overrun the paper" and "File plot1.png not found"   and also "conversion program vg2png not found, though I have installed vega and node.js on Windows.

Comment: Is it also possible to include it as a vectorial graphic? either svg or pdf