# Save gvis Object as png image

Tags: r, image, google-visualization, googlevis

I wanted to save the `gvis` object as `.png` file

```
Gauge <-  gvisGauge(CityPopularity,
options=list(min=0, max=800, greenFrom=500,
greenTo=800, yellowFrom=300, yellowTo=500,
redFrom=0, redTo=300, width=400, height=300))
plot(Gauge)

print(Gauge, tag="chart", file="Gauge.html")
```

I can save them as `.html` file - I need them be to be saved as `.png` file.
How can i save charts produced from `googleVis` as image (`.png`). I wanted to do this inside R.

Comment: You can use `export_png` command (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27193693/707145)).

Comment: Its a `gvis` object - and i am using `windows`